# SQL: How to insert at the beginning of a table with auto increment?

Tags: sql

I have a table with auto increment row keyid.

The table represents assignments. So like:

```
keyid | assignment
------------------
1     | assignmen1
2     | assignmen2
3     | assignmen3
4     | assignmen4
```

Now I have assignment5 but it's a high priority assignment. The code logic always consumes the first assigment in the table. So I would like the table to end up looking like:

```
keyid | assignment
-------------------
1     | assignment5
2     | assignment1
3     | assignment2
4     | assignment3
5     | assignment4
```

The keyid row is auto-increment. Doing this preinsert was not a requirement when I originall design the table.

Is there an insert query that can do this?

Otherwise I either need to add a priority column or do something like:

```
UPDATE myTable SET keyid = (keyid+1);
INSERT INTO myTable (keyid,assignment) VALUES (1,"assigment#");
```

For every assignment I need to insert at the beginning (I haven't tried these queeries, but Imagine they would work).

Are there better options? One thing I do KNOW the table is never too large. (like never more than 1K rows).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Updating keys is nearly always a really bad idea - for  a start it will break any foreign key relationships that you have. If you need to have a priority order that can change over time then just add a priority column and update that as necessary

Comment: Yeah. I will probably add the column. Although I know for a fact there will never be any other prioriy other than top priority and the there are no foreign key. This table is scrapable data that can be altered or delted in ahearbeat and is always done via manual scirpt. But even so, pracites are good practies.

Comment: If the table is scrapable as you describe then why not just truncate it and re-load it?

Comment: More work, I guess. I would need to read it and the add the new assignment and the reinsert it all. Can't do that with a couple of queries. But the problem is already solved. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "priority" is a newly introduced business concept, then the tables must be changed so as to reflect that concept.

If you don't, then, for example, if someone comes about with assignment6 that is also "high priority", how are you going to know that you must now not insert "at the start of the table", but "after Assignment5" instead ?  Or, what are you going to do when someone invents "medium priority" so that after that, you now have to insert "somewhere" "in the middle" ?

I don't remember by heart whether it's rule zero or rule 1, but "all information in the database must be represented in one and only one way : as values of attributes ("columns") in tuples ("rows") in relations ("tables")".

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. I'll gues I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

> Are there better options? One thing I do KNOW the table is never too large. (like never more than 1K rows).

Yes, you can do this way:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (assignment) VALUES ('assignment5');
UPDATE table1 SET keyid = keyid + 1 WHERE keyid > 0;
```

Also you can use a stored procedure to insert the new row at the beginning of the table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_at_beginning(new_assignment VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

  DECLARE new_keyid INT;

  INSERT INTO table1 (assignment) VALUES (new_assignment);
  SET new_keyid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

  UPDATE table1 SET keyid = keyid + 1 WHERE keyid > 0;

  RETURN new_keyid;

END;
```

Comment: Don't encourage bad ideas.